# How can I split keywords?

Tags: php, html, keyword

Currently, my keyword is showing:

```
tag[symbol] keyword1,keyword2,keyword3
```

I want to make it showing something like:

```
tag[symbol] keyword1, tag[symbol] keyword2, tag[symbol] keyword3
```

Code :

```
<span class="label label-default" style="padding:5px; margin-right:5px;">   
    <i class="fa fa-tag"></i>
    <?php echo isset($page->meta_keywords) ? $page->meta_keywords : $site->homepage_meta_keywords; ?> 
</span>
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What does `$keywords` contain ? Is it a string ?
Maybe try something like this :

```
<?php
// Store string in a variable
$keywords = isset($page->meta_keywords) ? $page->meta_keywords : $site->homepage_meta_keywords;
$keywords = split(",", $keywords); // Convert string in array
$i = 0;
$len = count($keywords);
foreach ($keywords as $key => $keyword): // Loop through array and display keywords ?>
    <span class="label label-default" style="padding:5px; margin-right:5px;">
        <i class="fa fa-tag"></i> <?php echo $keyword; ?>
    </span>
    <?php if ($i < $len - 1) echo ", "; ?>
<?php $i++; endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<span class="label label-default" style="padding:5px; margin-right:5px;">   
<?
if(isset($page->meta_keywords){
    foreach($site->homepage_meta_keywords as $keyword){
        echo $keyword;
    }
}
<i class="fa fa-tag"></i>
?>
</span>
```

Ok just wrote this up as some quick psuedo code, going to check it real fast